# ELK6.6.1: new added fields in filebeat not passing to logstash or ElasticSearch

Tags: elastic-stack

I added new field in filebeat.yml
as below:

```
filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /home/kren/ELK/docker-elk/original-logs-000/testa/feedaggregator/*
  tags: ["java"]
  fields: 
      app_id: java
  #fields_under_root: true
```

I could not see this new field in ES via Kibana and tried using it in logstash config and doesn't work

```
if [fields][app_type] == "java" or "%{[fields][app_type]}" == "java" {
      grok {
          match => {"message" =>"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:Loglevel}%{SPACE}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
          overwrite => ["message"]

      }
  }
```

anyone could help please? how to test it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found problem.
app_id: "java"
need the double quote for the string value